# Powershell issue renaming many files to remove certain characters

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a foler which contains a few thousand PDFs named like XXX_CON.100.1.pdf, XXX_CON.101.1.pdf etc.  I just want to remove the characters 'XXX_' from all filenames but I simply cannot get this to work.  I have tried the following commands:

Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$*.Name -replace "XXX*", "" }

Get-ChildItem -Filter 'XXX_*' | Rename-Item -NewName {$*.name -replace 'XXX*','' }

Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$*.name.substring(4,$*.BaseName.length-4) + $_.Extension}

Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'XXX_*.pdf','*.pdf' }

ls | Where {$*.FullName -match '(XXX*)'} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace ("XXX_","") }

Every single command gives me the Powershell error "Rename-Item : The parameter is incorrect."

e.g:

Rename-Item : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:23
+ Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$*.name.substring(4,$*.BaseName.leng ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\TempPE\pdf\XXX_CON.99.1.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

The crazy thing is if I run these with a -Whatif at the end they all appear to work... but when I take that parameter off they all fail again.

Anyone know what the issue is here?  TBH I googled to get the examples above but I'm sure they should work yet none of them do and I'm not enough of a Powershell guru to know how to get this to work.  It seems it just doesn't like Rename-Item no matter what I try which is really strange.  Could it be because all the files have more than dot in them?

Comment: OK, so I think is a system issue to do with renaming a file starting with 'CON.' because if I try to rename the files individually I get the error 'The specified device name is invalid'. I assume is some ancient windows thing to do with output device of Console.  I don't know how to get around this - they have to be named CON.xxx.x.pdf because they are loaded into an accounting system that needs to search for the exact filename... anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `get-childitem xxx_* | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'xxx_','' }` works for me with PS 5.1 and the same `xxx_con_*.*` filenames.

Comment: Thanks dxiv, but you are adding an extra _ at the end of the 'CON' which does not work for me - they have to be called CON.xxx.x.pdf not CON_.xxx.x.pdf

Comment: This issue can be replicated - in any folder try to create a new text file called 'CON.111.1.txt' and Windows will give you the 'specified device name is invalid' error.

Comment: Right, it was working because of that extra `_`. Without it it fails, but at least I am getting a (slightly) more intelligible error "*Cannot create a file when that file exists ... WriteError*".

Comment: Well I'm floored TBH.  This is one of the wierdest windows issues I've ever hit and I've been using it snce Windows 3.1!  Seems I have a real issue because as this page points out there are a whole pile of things you can't name a file or folder: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-cant-i-create-a-folder-with-name/23c86662-4988-4c7d-9c2d-3e33d4413de3

Comment: Funny thing is that I can copy such a file at the cmd prompt with `copy "\\?\%cd%\xxx_con.a.b" "\\?\%cd%\con.a.b"` but it seems I can't just rename it.

Comment: P.S. I'll take some of that back, the file can be created that way but programs will get confused when trying to access it.

Comment: More P.S. What makes this even sillier is that by Windows rules a complete filename of `CON.A.B` has an extension of `B` and a name of `CON.A` so it doesn't even match the [reserved name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) `CON`. Someone at MS must have misunderstood their own rules.